# how to implement avro alias

Tags: hive, avro

I am new to avro and while trying to use avro alias property i am getting below error.

Query : `select department_id , office_name from test.depart_alias;`

**SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:23 Invalid table alias or column reference 'office_name': (possible column names are: department_id, department_name)**

My json file for avsc format is

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "departments",
  "doc" : "Sqoop import of departments",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "department_id",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "department_id",
    "sqlType" : "4"
  }, {
    "name" : "department_name",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "aliases" : [ "office_name" ],
    "columnName" : "department_name",
    "sqlType" : "12"
  } ],
  "tableName" : "departments"
```

I want to use office name as alias to department_name. 
How should i implement it

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if your old column field is named department_name your schema should looks like this

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "departments",
  "doc" : "Sqoop import of departments",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "department_id",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "department_id",
    "sqlType" : "4"
  }, {
    "name" : "office_name",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "aliases" : [ "department_name" ], <- old columns here
    "columnName" : "department_name",
    "sqlType" : "12"
  } ],
  "tableName" : "departments"
```

Old column names or "aliases" should go inside of the aliases array.

Comment: Thanks @lake it worked.
Do you have any resource where i can learn more about schema evolution with example , please  share :)

Comment: this is ag ood place to start :) http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#schema_complex